# Execução de hover para rede social

Tags: html5, css3, css-hover

Como fazer para que quando ocorra a execução do hover nas redes sócias ele não movimente todos as redes sócias, somente a que tiver com o mouse e as outras fiquem fixa?

Todas elas estão se movimentando quando coloco o mouse.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
   margin: auto -1px auto auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 10px;
  font-size: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  margin: auto -5px auto auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aumentar o tamanho da fonte para ter esse efeito não é o ideal.

Uma das soluções e usando o `transform:scale` para aumentar o tamanho dos ícones no `:hover`. No caso eu passei o ícone do tamanho normal 100% scale(1), para 110% scale(1.1), que seria o mesmo que passar a fonte de 20px para 22px (10% a mais que o tamanho original)

Veja no exemplo abaixo como fica.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.fa {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
   margin: auto -1px auto auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}

.fa-youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
      
</body>
</html>
```